# Is it possible to import a Typescript into a running instance of ts-node REPL?

Tags: typescript, import, module, read-eval-print-loop, ts-node

I would like to test some Typescript code I've code written.

So far, the best way I know to do this is to run `ts-node my-file-name.ts`.

However I would like to make this more interactive, similar to how Python REPL allows you to import modules and then call then functions from the REPL however you'd like.

For example, a session might look like

```
$ ts-node
> import my-file-name.ts
> myFunctionFromMyFile("specialParam")
> "you just called a function from my-file-name.ts with param specialParam"
```

Is this possible with `ts-node`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way I've found to do this is as follows:

```
$ ts-node
> import * as abc from './my-file'
> abc.myFunction()
> "works!"
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks very much.

Comment: Bear in mind that as of now, this won't work if you have `noUnusedLocals` set in your compiler options. See https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/850. A workaround is to run `ts-node -O '{"noUnusedLocals": false}'` (make sure to use double quotes for the option name) to start up the REPL.

Comment: I get: _Cannot use import statement inside the Node.js REPL, alternatively use dynamic import._  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073219/ts-node-cant-use-dynamic-imports-or-import-statements-while-in-repl-or-eval-in

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you need something that is auto-imported on each REPL session, you could expose your app in a file and then use `repl.start` inside that file. For example, create `console.ts` like this:

```
import repl from 'repl';
import * as models from './models';

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  global[modelName] = models[modelName];
});

const replServer = repl.start({
  prompt: 'app > ',
});

replServer.context.db = models;
```

And run the console using

```
$ node --require ts-node/register/transpile-only --experimental-repl-await console
```

More details [here](https://sapandiwakar.in/rails-like-console-for-node-js-and-node-ts-2/)