# ts-node can't use dynamic imports or import statements while in repl or eval in the cli

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I have been trying to run eval or import esm module from the repl and I just can't make it work. I have tried a few things I found on the internet.
ex: [Is it possible to import a Typescript into a running instance of ts-node REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193529/is-it-possible-to-import-a-typescript-into-a-running-instance-of-ts-node-repl)

Not sure I am missing something, errors I am getting are:

1. from REPL with dynamic imports:

```
var a = await import("./test").then(x=>x)
//or
var a = await import("./test").then(x=>x)
//gives
//TypeError [ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING]: A dynamic import callback was not specified.
```

2. using import statements on REPL

```
import * as test from './src/test';
//works but then when I try to use 'test' it gives
//SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement inside the Node.js REPL, alternatively use dynamic import
```

3. using on the cli

```
ts-node --esm -e  "import * as z from './src/test'; console.log(z); export {}"
//gives
//Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

```
ts-node --esm -e "const z= import('./src/test').then(console.log);"
//gives
//TypeError [ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING]: A dynamic import callback was not specified.
```

Any ideas what is going on?

I am using ts-node 10.9.1 globally installed in node 18.2.0

Comment: Hi Ricardo, were you able to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/2005