# TypeScript: how to interactively import an ESM from REPL?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

The goal: to `import` a local `.ts` ESM module from a REPL. Here's [a reproducible project](https://github.com/oatmealb/ts-node-repl-import).

I'm using ESM modules and have `"type":"module"` set in `package.json`. Currently using `ts-node` (`v10.9.1`) but open to alternatives. What settings should I have in `tsconfig.json`, and/or elsewhere, to make *any* of the following work?

```
import sql from './db.js'
import sql from './db.ts'
await import('./db.ts')
await import('./db')
// etc.; I'll take anything :)
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": [ "src" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules", "dist" ],
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2023"],
    "module": "Node16",
    "target": "es2022",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext"
  }
}
```

---

For a specific example, I'm importing ['postgres' library](https://github.com/porsager/postgres) in this db.ts file:

```
import postgres from 'postgres'
const sql = postgres('localhost:5432',{
  host                 : process.env.DB_HOST,
  port                 : Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  database             : process.env.DB_NAME,
  username             : process.env.DB_USER,
  password             : process.env.DB_PASS,
})
export default sql
```

And `foo.ts` merely contains a toy query:

```
import sql from './db.js'
console.log(await sql`select starelid from pg_statistic limit 1`);
```

This works and can be called as:
`set -a && source ./.env && ts-node src/foo.ts`

How can I import either of the two .ts files from `ts-node` or other REPL?

---

A 'dynamic import' sadly errors as well.

*With* `.ts` extension:

```
ts-node
> foo = await import('./src/foo.ts')
Uncaught SyntaxError: 
export {};
^

'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

*Without* `.ts` extension:

```
> foo = await import('./src/foo')
Uncaught:
TypeError [ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING]: A dynamic import callback was not specified.
    at Object.execCommand (/Users/me/.asdf/installs/nodejs/18.16.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/repl.ts:633:32)
    at runInContext (/Users/me/.asdf/installs/nodejs/18.16.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/repl.ts:673:19)
    at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:129:12)
    at /path/to/project/<repl>.ts:3:4
    at /path/to/project/<repl>.ts:1:18
    at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:39:9)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:490:5) {
  code: 'ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING'
}
```

---

[Ricardo had an almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073219/ts-node-cant-use-dynamic-imports-or-import-statements-while-in-repl-or-eval-in) (and I also can't figure out how [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193529/is-it-possible-to-import-a-typescript-into-a-running-instance-of-ts-node-repl) should work, if at all).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** It used to work previously, but it no longer does. There is an [issue open about this on GitHub](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/2005) now.

---

It should work out of the box in `ts-node`, at least if you omit the `.ts` extension in the import. If you don't, you'll get an error that tells you about it and also tells you the two solutions: either omit `.ts` or enable the `allowImportingTsExtensions` setting.

```
$ ts-node
> import { bar } from './foo.ts'
<repl>.ts:4:21 - error TS5097: An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.

4 import { bar } from './foo.ts'
                      ~~~~~~~~~~

> import { bar } from './foo'
undefined
> bar()
hello world
undefined
>
```

> An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out a helpless TS newbie! Sadly, I get (different) errors either _with_ or _without_ `.ts` extension, as seen in my updated question (along with full `tsconfig.json`). I'll prepare an example repo.

Comment: I've added [an example repo, reproducible with only 3 commands](https://github.com/oatmealb/ts-node-repl-import).

Comment: Hi @VanillaDonuts, were you able to solve this?

Comment: Hi @NihalJoshi, sadly no. Still looking.

Comment: It seems when I tested this, I was using an older version of `ts-node`. With the current version I can reproduce it too. It seems [it's an open issue for many months on GitHub](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/2005).